# express js, connection refused to endpoints from other computers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, jwt

I have an express server setup and React for the frontend. The express server is running on port 5000 and react on 3000. I'm also using JWT tokens.

If i login to the app from the computer its running on everything is fine. I can access the api endpoints and get data back.

If i login from another computer that is on the same network using to local IP. I can get to the react front end, i can login too. But if i try to access any of the api endpoint which are running on localhost:5000, i get err connection refused. Everything seems ok in the settings, i can't figure out what the issue is. Could it be Windows' firewall blocking? Or simply by router?

Note, i also tried with NGROK which behaves the same way. I tried Heroku which is worse, i cannot even login, it seems me that the input fields are required even tough i type something in there, it's like it's sending an empty object to the backend whenever i use Heroku.

**Express Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')

const users = require("./routes/api/users");
const tickets = require("./routes/api/tickets");
const alerts = require("./routes/api/alerts");
const avaya = require("./routes/api/avaya");
const exercises = require("./routes/api/exercises");

const app = express();

// CORS Middleware

app.use(cors())
// Bodyparser middleware
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());



// DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(
    db,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB successfully connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// Routes
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use('/api/tickets', tickets);
app.use('/api/alerts', alerts);
app.use('/api/avaya', avaya);
app.use('/api/exercises', exercises);


// Serve static assets if in production
// if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
//     // Set static folder
//     app.use(express.static('client/build'));

//     app.get('*', (req, res) => {
//       res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
//     });
//   }

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port} !`));
```

Comment: Do you mean your react app actually make request for `http://localhost:5000`? It needs to make a request to `http://servername:5000` instead where `servername` is the hostname or IP address of your server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make your clientside axios request target your IPv4 Address and the port of your server also make sure that you can access your IPv4 Address:5000 using postman or anything similar

Comment: What about when the app is on Heroku? It wouldn't target my IP anymore, would make sense to leave localhost no?

Comment: You sould not leave your clientside webpage ip like localhost. because when you upload your files when someone else enter your site he will get the point on localhost ip and he will not know anything about localhost. client side ip must target the server

Comment: Does express need to run at the same time as Heroku? Maybe I don't understand how Heroku works. I thought it was running it all, node express react in their server. But you're saying I need to put my IPv4 address in there?

Comment: I said that you client side app needs to target your server ip. if you are running your server localhost then target your IPv4 address if you are running it in a public server then targer public server ip